# Georeferencing scale error

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, scale

I have a map scan (scale 1:500, CRS probably: ETRS89 / UTM Zone 33N) and want to georeference it.
Therefore, I set a ground map (Google Satellite, CRS: WGS 84/ Pseudo Mercator).
After georeferencing, the scaling of my map is incorrect. My area has grown from 1250 m² to 3000 m².
On the fly projecting is enabled and I also set the project CRS manually to Pseudo Mercator.

Does anyone have any idea of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of Pseudo Mercator? Pseudo Mercator is not a proper Coordinate System to measure areas. Depending where you are on Planet Earth, there can be huge differences in area-size compared to other coordinate systems that try to reduce distortion.

Comment: Maybe it is my fault, but I cannot change the CRS of my basemap (Pseudo Mercator).
I'm loading the basemap by using the Openlayer plugin.

Comment: My advice, use the Quickmapservices Plugin (to get Google Satellite: Settings --> More Services). Set your project CRS to ETRS89 / UTM Zone 33N (you do not have to change the CRS of your background map) and do also the georeferencing with UTM.